# Using SED to comment or uncomment a line in YAML

Tags: linux, bash, sed, yaml

I am trying to comment or uncomment a line using Sed in yaml , couldn't find a method using yq.

```
        - files:
            force-magic: no   # force logging magic on all logged files
            # force logging of checksums, available hash functions are md5,
            # sha1 and sha256
            #force-hash: [md5]
```

I tried these commands as I have white space
sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^[#[:space:]]*/#/g' file to comment out,*
sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^[#[:space:]]//g' file to uncomment
But issue is that they are removing space , which make yaml format truncated.
Ex :

```
        - files:
            force-magic: no   # force logging magic on all logged files
            # force logging of checksums, available hash functions are md5,
            # sha1 and sha256
force-hash: [md5]
```

I want to comment / uncomment this force-hash line , in such a way that it maintain it yaml properties i.e to be part of files array
Expected  output

```
        - files:
            force-magic: no   # force logging magic on all logged files
            # force logging of checksums, available hash functions are md5,
            # sha1 and sha256
            force-hash: [md5]
```

```
Solution
sed 's/force-hash/\# force-hash/g' <name_of_file> #this will comment your line   
sed 's/#\(force-hash.*\)/\1/' <name_of_file> #to uncomment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is a way with `yq`, I just do not have a need to learn it at this time, so here is an option using `sed`.

```
$ sed 's/#\(force-hash.*\)/\1/' input_file
 - files:
            force-magic: no   # force logging magic on all logged files
            # force logging of checksums, available hash functions are md5,
            # sha1 and sha256
            force-hash: [md5]
```

Comment: Hi @HatLess how to comment it with your method.

Comment: You can reverse the order like so: `sed 's/\(force-hash.*\)/#\1/' input_file`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly but if you want to comment and uncomment known text you can do it as:

```
sed 's/force-hash/\# force-hash/g' <name_of_file> #this will comment your line
sed 's/# force-hash/\force-hash/g' <name_of_file> #this will uncomment your line
```

you don't need to address those whitespaces since you need them, just replace the word with #word.

- if you got what you wanted you can add the -i flag which I removed above for testing.

Comment: You understood the problem

Comment: But Uncomment method is not working . It makes this : ^Lorce-hash: [sha1, md5]     , Its replacing # force with ^Lorce

Comment: That's weird, It works on my mac with -i '.extension', which OS are you using?
you can also try backslash the # and the - like sed 's/\# force\-hash/\force\-hash/g'

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 , this didn't work but  sed 's/#\(force-hash.*\)/\1/' input_file  this worked ... last question there are two such force-hash lines in my file how to make sure it changes only 1st occurence of this line .. Thanks

Comment: this should do the trick 
sed '0,/force-hash/{s/force-hash/# force-hash}'

Comment: This gives ed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command

Comment: missng slash, sorry, use this: sed '0,/force-hash/{s/force-hash/# force-hash/}'